# Init Login Before View Website in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

same as title, i want everybody when visit my site, first, must be login (look like facebook or twitter...) (i using yii framework)
i try using:

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        'loginUrl'=>array('site/login'),
    ),
);
```

or:

```
public function init()
    {
        if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
        {
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                echo $error['message'];
            else
            {
                if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            {
                $this->layout='//layouts/login';
                $this->render('error',$error);
            }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            {
                $this->layout='//layouts/login';
                $this->render('login');
            }
        }
    }
```

but not work, somebody can help me???

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible ways here:

Preloading the component:

I'm assuming that the `init()`-function you shared here is part of your own application-component (perhaps a derived `CWebUser`, which would make most sense). If so, just add the "user" to the "preload" setting of your config (so before the components starts:

```
return array(
   ...
   'preload' => array('user'),
   'components' => array(
       ...
);
```

(normally it should already be there, since the "log" component is also pre-loaded).

1 remark though: If this is derived of another `CApplicationComponent`, don't forget to *call the parent init function*.

Controller `beforeAction`:

Add your own controller and use that as a base for everything:

```
class MyController extends CController
{
    protected boolean beforeAction(CAction $action)
    {
        // Check if user is logged in and do logic if not
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
}
```

Given your `init()`-function, the first might be the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Yii access control. Read all about it here :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

The way you will do this is by adding a special function to your controller :

```
class MyController extends CController
{

public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'list' and 'show' actions
            'actions'=>array('login','register'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
...
}
```

The name of the function must be accessRules.

It works as follows :-

- All users are allowed to access the login and register actions. You must have this otherwise user's will have to log in to go to the login page !
- Users that are authenticated (in other words, logged in successfully), are allowed to perform all other actions
- If somehow somebody falls through the loops, we deny all other actions as a safety net.

Look here for a good example and explanation on how to implement this : http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/14/yii-framework-access-control-lists/